# Wordpress as an endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

So, I'm building something and need to use wordpress as an endpoint.

I’ve a post url like http://example.com/sample-post. Now I’ve added a rewrite endpoint “edit”. So the url becomes http://example.com/sample-post/edit. Now whats the right way to print the url? Should it be like:

```
<?php echo get_permalink() . '/edit'; ?>
```

or is there any prefered way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be the preferred way. However, I recommend writing a function in *functions.php* to do some additional checks before printing the link:

```
function get_custom_edit_link() {
    // Check if we're on a Post page
    return is_single() ? get_permalink() . '/edit' : '';
}
```

And then in your template, call it with:

```
echo get_custom_edit_link();
```

However, if you're using this link to head to *edit.php*, you may want to consider using [the `get_edit_link()` method of the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_posts_list_table/get_edit_link/).